# Global variable in EventHandler

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, event-handling

I have a problem. As you can see in below, I have a button event and in that event I have MySub and an event handler attached to it. While traversing myListDataGridView.Rows I am trying to log each iteration with ID. But I am not sure but, because of handler starts a new thread(maybe), I can't get the right ID. For example logging row 2, other parameters ok but I get 4th row ID. I can solve this problem via sending ID as parameter to MySub and return it but I am trying to find another way.Because of some company reasons. Could you help me ? Thanks in advance.

```
Public Class X
   Dim myVariable As Integer = 0

   AddHandler MySub, AddressOf MySubHandler

   Private Sub OKBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OkBtn.Click
       For Each d As DataGridViewRow In myListDataGridView.Rows 'rowcount 750
           MySub(d.Cells("ABC").Value)
           myVariable = d.Cells("ID")
       Next
   End Sub

   Private Sub MySubHandler(Data As MySubReply)
      ........
      ........
      Log(myVariable, other parameters)
   End Sub

End Class
```

I tried this code block but it locks UI. You can follow isHandlerJobDone variable.

```
Public Class X
   Dim myVariable As Integer = 0
   Dim isHandlerJobDone As Boolean

   AddHandler MySub, AddressOf MySubHandler

   Private Sub OKBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OkBtn.Click
       isHandlerJobDone = False
       For Each d As DataGridViewRow In myListDataGridView.Rows 'rowcount 750
           MySub(d.Cells("ABC").Value)
           myVariable = d.Cells("ID")
       While Not isHandlerJobDone
       End While
       Next
   End Sub

   Private Sub MySubHandler(Data As MySubReply)
      ........
      ........
      Log(myVariable, other parameters)
      isHandlerJobDone = True
   End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You aren't using events here.  You are just calling the method through a delegate.  Guessing you should try raising the event through the [RaiseEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/raiseevent-statement) statement.  Or just use a BackgroundWorker or a Task to perform non-ui procedures in a separate thread.

Comment: There are no threads involved in the code as presented.  Everything runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Can you move the `Log()` call to within the For loop?  Why can't you change the MySubHandler() parameter signature?  Why use MySubHandler() at all?...

Comment: The parameter in `MySubHandler` is of type `MySubReply`.  Is that a CLASS or a STRUCT?  If it is a class, then instead of a global "myVariable" as type Integer, use a [DICTIONARY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) with a Key Type of `MySubReply`, and a Value Type of Integer so you can associate each `MySubReply` with its "ID".  Modify your log to lookup the associated ID and you're done...

Comment: I can't move Log() in loop because I am logging data that is returning from MySub(). By the way, if there is no new thread why the loop is not waiting the execution of MySubHandler and continues ?

Comment: You set `isHandlerJobDone = True` in MySubHandler. As soon as the `OkBtn.Click` reaches the While loop it is an infinite loop. There is not code in the loop to set `isHandlerJobDone` back to `False`. Lock up!

Comment: @Idle_Mind  MySubReply is a class, but it is returning value from MySub. How can I associate them ? Mary I edited while part

Answer (score 0):

> MySubReply is a class

Try something like this, then, using a [Dictionary(Of MySubReply, Integer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1):

```
Public Class X

    Private ID_Lookup As New Dictionary(Of MySubReply, Integer)

    Private Sub OKBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OkBtn.Click
        ID_Lookup.Clear()
        For Each d As DataGridViewRow In myListDataGridView.Rows 'rowcount 750
            Dim data As MySubReply = DirectCast(d.Cells("ABC").Value, MySubReply)
            ID_Lookup.Add(data, CInt(d.Cells("ID"))) ' associate the ID with this data
            MySub(data)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub MySubHandler(Data As MySubReply)
        Dim ID As Integer = ID_Lookup.Item(Data) ' retrieve the ID based on Data
        ' ... use "ID" somehow ...
        Log(myVariable, other parameters)
    End Sub

End Class
```